# while(getline()) loop never getting executed when reading a text file?

Tags: c++, while-loop, fstream, ifstream

I have a bigger project I am working on but the simple loop to go through each line of text in a text file does not work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
       string input; 
       cout << "Input file name: "; 
       cin >> input; 
       string fName = "\"" + input + "\""; 

       ifstream myfile(fName.c_str()); 
       string content; 
       int count = 0; 

       while(getline(myfile, content)){
              count++;
       }

       cout << count << endl;
       myfile.close();

       return 0;
}
```

...cout just ends up printing 0. It never enters the while loop. What am I doing wrong? This is just a simple program I put together to showcase the issue. I am compiling using: `g++ -std=c++11 -Wall tst.cc -o test` and the text file I'm reading from is called test.txt and it has this inside:

```
Hello world!
It is my pleasure
to introduce you!
```

Any and all tips are extremely appreciated!

Comment: You never check if the file is actually opened. Are you certain you need to quote the string?

Comment: aside, I'm pretty sure you can pass a string object directly to ifstream constructor

Comment: Ahhh okay, that seems to have fixed it thank you. I put it in quotes because when i was looking up other posts, every time they open up a file they always put the file name in quotes such as: ifstream stream("file.txt") . Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, those quotation marks ruin the filename. Just call `ifstream myfile(input.c_str());` And ALWAYS check whether `ifstream` succeeded in opening the file before you try and do anything with it.

Comment: In `ifstream stream("file.txt")` the quotes are part of the C++ syntax, not part of the parameter passed to the constructor.

Comment: The quotes indicate that the file name is a string, and not the name of some variable, function, etc. They are not part of the string. Also, like other C++ standard library functions that take strings, the constructor of `ifstream` can take an `std::string` just fine, so no need for `.cstr()`.